# How do I calculate the mean of two different variables taking into account the values of latitude and longitude in R?

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, bioinformatics, mean, biometrics

I am currently trying to obtain some data in R from a table.

I have a dataset with two different variables, the annual range and the annual mean, of the worldwide sea surface temperature (SST). I have these values for each latitude (from 90 to -90) and longitude (from 180 to -180) level.

I would like to obtain the mean of the aforementioned variables (annual range and annual mean) for 5x5 grid cells of latitude/longitude. For example, I would need to know the "annual range" mean for for a longitude between -180 and -176 and a latitude between 90 and 86, and so on until getting the mean of this variable for all the possible 5x5 grid cells.

My data looks like:

`lon  lat ANNUAL_MEAN ANNUAL_RANGE
1 0.5 89.5        -1.8            0
2 1.5 89.5        -1.8            0
3 2.5 89.5        -1.8            0
4 3.5 89.5        -1.8            0
5 4.5 89.5        -1.8            0
6 5.5 89.5        -1.8            0
...
52001 354.5 -89.5        -1.8            0
52002 355.5 -89.5        -1.8            0
52003 356.5 -89.5        -1.8            0
52004 357.5 -89.5        -1.8            0
52005 358.5 -89.5        -1.8            0
52006 359.5 -89.5        -1.8            0`

Thank you in advance

Comment: Show us some data and code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `raster` package and its `focal` function for computations with a moving window.

First I will create a dummy data.frame which represents your data

```
# Prepare dummy data.frame
set.seed(2222)
lonlat <- expand.grid(1:10, 1:10)
df <- data.frame( lon = lonlat[, 1],
                  lat = lonlat[, 2],
                  ANNUAL_MEAN = rnorm(100),
                  ANNUAL_RANGE = runif(100, 1, 5)
                )
```

Now we have to convert data frame into raster and to perform a moving window averaging.

```
library(raster)

# Convert data frame to raster object
rdf <- df
coordinates(rdf) <- ~ lon + lat
gridded(rdf) <- TRUE
rdf <- brick(rdf) # our raster brick

## Perform moving window averaging

# prepare weights matrix (5*5)
w <- matrix(1, ncol = 5, nrow = 5)

# perform moving window averaging
ANNUAL_MEAN_AVG <- focal(rdf[[1]], w, mean, pad = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)
ANNUAL_RANGE_AVG <- focal(rdf[[2]], w, mean, pad = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)

# Append new data to initial data.frame
df$ANNUAL_MEAN_AVG <- as.data.frame(ANNUAL_MEAN_AVG)
df$ANNUAL_RANGE_AVG <- as.data.frame(ANNUAL_RANGE_AVG)
```

Now each cell in `df$ANNUAL_MEAN_AVG` and `df$ANNUAL_RANGE_AVG` contains the mean value of the corresponding 5*5 square.

**UPD 1. 5x5 downsampling**

If you need a fixed 5x5 grid cells with mean values per cell you can use `raster::agregate` function.

Working with `rdf` raster brick from the previous example.

```
# perform an aggregation with given downsampling factor
rdf_d <- aggregate(rdf, fact=5, fun = mean)

# Now each pixel in the raster `rdf_d` contains a mean value of 5x5 pixels from initial `rdf`
# we need to get pixels coordinates and their values
coord <- coordinates(rdf_d)
vals <- as.data.frame(rdf_d)
colnames(coord) <- c("lon", "lat")
colnames(vals) <- c("ANNUAL_MEAN_AVG", "ANNUAL_RANGE_AVG")

res <- cbind(coord, vals)
```

Comment: My understanding is that Diego needs a 2-dimensional binning (bucketing) with mean values per bin, rather than a 2-dimensional moving average?

Comment: According to this phrase: "the mean of this variable for all the possible 5x5 grid cells." I understand that he needs moving average

Comment: I am sorry, I think my explanation was not good enough. But yes, @stenevang is right, I would need fixed 5x5 grid cells with mean values per cell.

Comment: Alright, we can use `raster::agregate` for 5x5 downsampling.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I got what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that uses the dplyr package, included in tidyverse. It should be easy to follow, step by step.

```
library(tidyverse)

# set.seed() assures reproducability of the example with identical random numbers
set.seed(42)


# build a simulated data set as described in the question
lats <- seq(from = -90, to = 90, by = 0.5)
lons <- seq(from = -180, to = 179.5, by = 0.5) # we must omit +180 or we would
                                               # double count those points
                                               # since they coincide with -180

    # combining each latitude point with each longitude point
coord <- merge(lats, lons) %>%
    rename(lat = x) %>% 
    rename(lon = y) %>%
    # adding simulated values
    mutate(annual_mean = runif(n = nrow(.), min = -2, max = 2)) %>%
    mutate(annual_range = runif(n = nrow(.), min = 0, max = 3)) %>% 
    # defining bands of 5 latitude and 5 longitude points by using integer division
    mutate(lat_band = lat%/%5) %>% 
    mutate(lon_band = lon%/%5) %>% 
    # creating a name label for each unique 5x5 gridcell
    mutate(gridcell_5x5 = paste(lat_band, lon_band, sep = ",")) %>%
    # group-by instruction, much like in SQL
    group_by(lat_band, lon_band, gridcell_5x5) %>% 
    # sorting to get a nice order
    arrange(lat_band, lon_band) %>% 
    # calculating minimum and maximum latitude and longitude for each gridcell
    # calculating the mean values per gridcell
    summarize(gridcell_min_lat = min(lat), 
              gridcell_max_lat = max(lat),
              gridcell_min_lon = min(lon),
              gridcell_max_lon = max(lon),
              gridcell_mean_annual_mean = round(mean(annual_mean), 3),
              gridcell_mean_annual_range = round(mean(annual_range), 3) )
```

Comment: I tried your script but I got fake values of the means, and I think it is due to script lacking of an association with the original vales of ANNUAL_RANGE and ANNUAL_MEAN of my dataset. Could you please help me with this? Tanks in advance

Comment: My solution example contains randomly generated dummy values. You have to apply the solution to the real dataset. You should take your dataset and use my code starting from the comment line "#defining bands of 5..." etc. This should be a good leaning exercise for getting up to speed with using R.

Comment: @DiegoCepeda Of course the values do not correspond to the original. The comment saying that it uses simulated data seems very clear about this. If you want to use your data, read it from the file.

Comment: Yes, I know your example contains random data, I tried the script with my own data but I just checked some grid cells randomly, doing the calculation in Excell, and the results are completely different

Comment: If you compare to Excel, and get different results, one possible explanation could be that the gridcell limits have been picked differently. And also, is it "fixed" gridcells you want or a moving average of 5x5 for each single coordinate?

Comment: Maybe the gridcells' limits are different between R and Excell. I want fixed gridcells. I repeated the script and now I think I get more real results. But I have a problem: as I am working with R Studio, the final results that appear in the console are too big, so I cannot see all of them (the console has scrolled so far down that those things are cutoff at the top of the console). Is there a way to obtain the results in a table?

Comment: You should assign the resulting data frame to a name (like "df" or something) and then click that name to view the data in a scrollable table or do View(df). This however is very, very basic R and RStudio usage matters and you should probably go through an entry level R tutorial to learn things like that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help